# Return indented JSON from AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have my lambda function set up in java:

```
public class Handler implements RequestHandler <Request, List <Response>>
{
    public List <Response> handleRequest (Request request, Context context)
    {                       
        List <Response> userList = new ArrayList <Response>();

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            Response user = new Response();
            user.setUserID (Integer.parseInt (values[i][0]));
            user.setUserTypeName (values[i][1]);
            user.setUserEmail (values[i][2]);
            user.setUserFirstName (values[i][3]);
            user.setUserLastName (values[i][4]);
            user.setUserRole (values[i][5]);
            user.setActiveYN (values[i][6]);
            userList.add (user);
        }
        return userList;
    }
}
```

AWS API Gateway does its thing and and it returns an array of dummy objects just fine:

```
[{"userID":1,"userTypeName":"Adminstrator","userEmail":"joesmiley@gmail.com","userFirstName":"Joe","userLastName":"Smiley","userRole":"n/a","activeYN":"y"},
{"userID":2,"userTypeName":"Manager","userEmail":"sandyjones@gmail.com","userFirstName":"Sandy","userLastName":"Jones","userRole":"n/a","activeYN":"y"},
{"userID":3,"userTypeName":"Manager","userEmail":"jasonsmith@gmail.com","userFirstName":"Jason","userLastName":"Smith","userRole":"n/a","activeYN":"y"},
{"userID":4,"userTypeName":"Manager","userEmail":"neoanderson@gmail.com","userFirstName":"Neo","userLastName":"Anderson","userRole":"n/a","activeYN":"y"}]
```

The problem is im a stickler for neatness so this return service needs whitespace! As far as I know, my java method only has control on information and not on presentation. Is this small tweak possible?

#### **Edit**

Tried returning a JSONArray instead; Same result.

```
JSONArray indentedReturn = new JSONArray();
indentedReturn.addAll (userList);
return indentedReturn;
```

Comment: That whitespace would be extra bytes.  It would be easy enough to reformat a result for yourself at the receiver.  Alternatively, you could implement the formatting *in* AWS and return the formatted json string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need indentation you should do it on the client before displaying your JSON instead of sending whitespaces and line brakes over the network. If for whatever reason that's not an option you can format your objects to a JSON string inside your lambda function and return a string instead of a list.